# Why we use findAndCountAll in Sequelize(MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, database, orm, sequelize.js, backend

I don't know why we use Sequelize(MySQL) `findAndCountAll` method. Because it sends two queries and I think it's wasteful.

Assume we have a `Test` table like below.

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |

And call `findAndCountAll` and `findAll` method like below.

```
const result1 = await Test.findAndCountAll() --> {count: 2, rows: [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}]}
const result2 = await Test.findAll() --> [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}]
```

We can get `count` from result2 by call `length` (`result2.length`).

The `findAndCountAll` method sends the query twice, and the `findAll` method sends the query once.

```
-- findAndCountAll
SELECT count(*) FROM Test;
SELECT id, name FROM Test;

-- findAll
SELECT id, name FROM Test;
```

I think if we have so many rows in the `Test` table, this makes a large load(2 times than `findAll`) on the database.

That's why I thought `findAndCountAll` method is wasteful.

Is there a case what is `findAndCountAll` performs better than `findAll` and `length`? Or is there a reason why we use findAndCountAll method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole purpose of `findANdCountAll` is to use along with `limit` and `offset` options to organise server-side paging.
After you indicate both options (I strongly recommend adding the `order` option with a field or several fields so you will get predictable results of each page of records) you will see the main difference between the two SQL queries executed.
The `count` query will be without `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` options to find out the total number of records considering all conditions and sorting in the query. At the same time, the `select` query will be WITH `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` options to get an indicated "page" of records.

```sql
-- findAndCountAll
SELECT count(*)
FROM Test WHERE name like '%test%';

SELECT id, name
FROM Test
WHERE name like '%test%'
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0
ORDER BY name, id;
```

So here, for instance, you might get the total number of records equals to 100 and only 10 first records in the second select query.
That way you will know how many records you have and how many pages as well to be able to indicate the correct `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` options to get desired page with records.

Of course, if you don't plan to use such pagination and don't indicate `offset` and `limit` options then you don't need to use `findAndCountAll`. It's enough to use `findAll` and check `length` prop.